# I want to get rid of the not used spaces

Tags: r, ggplot2

In this case, I am trying to graph a barplot using ggplot2 but I am having the same names along with the groups and I would like to have different names per group. The names that I got on the x-axis are 
aa, bb, cc, dd, ee in group 1 
aa, bb, cc, dd, ee in group 2 
aa, bb, cc, dd, ee in group 3 
       but I want this
aa, bb, cc, dd, ee in group 1
ff, gg, hh, ii, jj in group 2
kk, ll, mm, nn, oo in group 3
thanks for the help.

```
library(ggplot2)
datos3 <- read.csv("datos3.csv")
p<- ggplot(datos3, aes(x=N2, y=x, fill=g))+
 geom_bar(stat="identity", color="black", position="dodge")+
 facet_wrap(. ~f)+
 geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=x-e, ymax=x+e), width=.2, position=position_dodge(.9)) +
 scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5), 
 labels = c("aa", "bb", "cc", "dd", "ee", "ff", "gg", "hh", "ii", "jj", "kk", "ll", "mm", "nn", "oo"))+
 theme(axis.text.x= element_text(angle=90, hjust=1))+
 labs(x = "Microorganismos", y = "Actividad enzimatica")
 p
```

On the other hand, How can't get rid off the empty values from the first graph? [image]

p[image]

Comment: Those are the x axis values, all you have to do is to change the values in each group of `f`, the faceting variable.

Comment: You also can't have identical x locations and different variables.  And to add more to @'Rui Barradas', your x locations should be 1 to 5 when f is 1, 6 to 10 when f=2, and 11 to 15 when f=3.

Comment: I updated the questions with your advice, it works but now I am having blank spaces

Answer (score 0):

Add `scales='free_x'` to the `facet_wrap()` call.  Example:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, disp)) + geom_point() + facet_wrap(~cyl)
```

[image]

Adding `scales='free_x'` argument results in removing the empty positions for mpg in the x axis:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, disp)) + geom_point() + facet_wrap(~cyl, scales = 'free_x')
```

[image]

#### Width of bars

Note that width of bars are not preserved for column plots when `scales='free'` is used-the width of the facet is preserved.  In your case, if each facet has the same number (5 columns), it's not a problem, but if you have different numbers of columns per facet, you end up with columns not the same width.  The fix there is to use `facet_grid()` instead of `facet_wrap()`, since with `facet_grid()` there is the argument `space=` that can fix that.  Here's an example:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(as.factor(mpg), disp)) +
    geom_col(fill='red',alpha=0.4) + 
    facet_wrap(~cyl, scales = 'free_x')
```

[image]

The width of the facets are preserved, not the width of the bars.  The fix is adding the `space=` argument, which means you have to switch to `facet_grid()`:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(as.factor(mpg), disp)) +
    geom_col(fill='red',alpha=0.4) +
    facet_grid(.~cyl, scales = 'free_x', space='free')
```

[image]

Fixed now - facets are different width to account for having different numbers of bars, each fixed at the same width.